# Variation on Regular Curve consists of Regular Curves

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, curves, differential

I posted this question here the other day but it didn't receive much attention. Perhaps because of the length of the post. So I shall take a minimalist approach here and link to the other question for all the extra details/hints.

Let γ$_s$ : I → R$^n$, s ∈ (−a, a), a > 0, be a variation with compact
support K ⊂ I$^{'}$ of a regular curve γ = γ$_0$. Show that there exists some 0 < b ≤ a
such that γs is a regular curve for all s ∈ (−b, b). Thus, we may assume w.l.o.g.
that any variation of a regular curve consists of regular curves

So I really am unfamiliar with the calculus of variations but I know that:
The variation $\gamma_s$ would be something like $\gamma(t + s\eta)$ with s ranging from (-a to a) with s = 0 corresponding to $\gamma$ and so presumably we must find an s (in the interval +/- b) such that the variation is regular?

I really need help on this so anyone who can offer some I would truly appreciate it.

Also the link to more info is in my previous post: [Any Variation of a regular curve consists of Regular Curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176626/any-variation-of-a-regular-curve-consists-of-regular-curves)

Comment: FYI: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23681/if-i-am-not-getting-feeback-for-my-questions-can-i-just-post-the-same-question

Comment: Do you have any textbook/ note?

Comment: Unfortunately I already asked my professor if there was a resource he could offer me to learn the material pertinent to these questions I've posted but he said that all the material was developed in class and to get notes from a classmate. Due to a number of reasons that wasn't the most viable option for me so I figured I'd turn here. I've basically just been using wikipedia

Comment: Then that make us extremely hard to answer your questions..... We do not know what terminology we can use that you understand.

Comment: How about coruse website, course outline?

Comment: Oh, well I tried to lay out the terminology that was given on the problem statement here and in my other question that I had linked to (there's more context there if you didnt check it out) I just figured people would answer in whatever Calculus of Variations notation they were familiar with and I would decipher it on my own. I appreciate, in spite of the ostensible futility in answering my question, your persistence and the help you've given me thus far @John Ma

Comment: Also the course website is useless. Just basically the syllabus and office hours and links to HW. Good suggestion though!